# Android Drag and Drop - Create a Folder on dropping an item over another using Recycler view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have implemented Drag and Drop functionality using ItemTouchHelper in GridView. I used the idea from [Paul Burke](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.eorrab4yy) 
I am able to re order and swap the items but i need to add another functionality to create a folder on dropping one file/item over another(dropping one grid item over another) .In the current implementation ***onItemMove*** is getting called while i hover one item to another ,I need to swap items only if we are hovering the dragged item in the middle of other two grid items .Is there any way to implement the same using ItemTouch Helper or i need to move to Android Default Drag and Drop Framework.

Comment: The stock recycler-helper code Google provides will allow movement within the recycler: up down, and left, right .  It will also allow swipe as if deleting.  To achieve what you want you're going to have use onStartDragListener and implement that yourself.

Comment: so instead of using ItemTouchHelper i need to implement the drag listner right ?

Comment: @Martin i'm having same doubt as Sujiz , Can you elaborate  , what you are suggesting to do so ?

Comment: @Sujiz have you found any solution?